# Block Method Calls in CMS Page

Tags: magento

Is there any a way to call Block method calls in CMS page?

What I am trying to do is. I have a hyperlink in my CMS Page and I want to retrieve the email address of the customer to pass it as a get variable which another website will use.

e.g. In CMS page I have

```
(someother website link)
<a href="www.xyz.com?email=<?php $getCutomer->getEmail();?>&&name=<?php $getCutomer->getName();?>
```

I know we can't add php in CMS pages or block. I have just shown you as an example what I want to achieve. 
So is there any way using XML or anything else?

Please Advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you simply include the .phtml file in CMS page or Static block as:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="path/to/your-custom-template.phtml"}}
```

and you can now use any php code in that .phtml file.

Cheers!

Comment: Buy why would i create a template file just for one method . Isn't there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes as MagePsycho said, you will need to create phtml file for calling block method or getting dynamic data.

In .phtml file, it's simple just call $this->getCustomerEmail() or whatever method you wrote to get customer email.

Comment: I am not saying that's wrong but I think that is not the best approach. What if I have 10 methods to call and then I would need to create 10 different template files.

Comment: If you have 10 methods (in 1 block) to call, you can do so in 1 .phtml file. One block file may be common to 10 template files.